# Build Response Entity without sending it

Tags: java, spring, entity, response

I have the following situation: In my spring application I make a request to another web service. This web service sends me a ResponseEntity back. Now I have modified the ResponseEntity this worked perfectly, except that I cannot build a new ResponseEntity, I don't know why. Can someone tell me how to build a new ResponseEntity?

Thats my code:

```
 JsonNode modifiedBody = //body
 HttpHeaders modifiedHeader = //header
 HttpEntity<Object> newResponse = new HttpEntity<>(modifiedBody, modifiedHeader);

 //until this point everything works perfect now I want to create a new ResponseEntity without calling a webservice
 ResponseEntity<Object> entity = //MAKE NEW RESPONSE ENTITY
```

Can someone please tell me how to make a new response entity without sending it?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Disappearing value:

[image]

If I look in the debugger I find the value. But in the next step its gone.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```java
ResponseEntity<Object> entity = ResponseEntity
                .status(200) // status
                .headers(...)
                .body(...); // maybe some body
```

Please note that you cannot pass HttpEntity there, so you must set headers and body through these static methods as well.

Comment: I can return the ResponseEntity. Unfortunately some information gets lost, could you help me with that?

Comment: return ResponseEntity.status(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).headers(newHeaders).body(newResponse);

Comment: Thats how I return my ResponseEntity when I look at the header / body it contains the information I need but when it arrives at the next stage the information is gone

Comment: The weird thing is that all the other values are there. Except the consent-id

Comment: @TryHard, there is probably a json serialization issue that is being ignored. It depends on the serializer you use. From the screenshot, I cannot understand what is happening, it looks like the `"consent-id"` does not have any value, which means this is invalid json. Are you returning `plain/text`? If one value is shown, but others are not its obvious the problem is in that value, so try to isolate a problem and debug further. Or create a separate question, which will target serialization problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem. From the third party api I got a content length, I passed this value on to my header. But since I modified the content, the length is not the same anymore and the program cuts away everything that is above that size

Comment: @TryHard, I am glad you found the solution! I smiled :) Please mark the answer as accepted if you don't mind

Comment: do you how how to handle this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553863/put-request-throws-401-no-body-error-and-cannot-be-stored-in-the-response-enti

Comment: I will answer that question, please mark my answer as accepted (hover to the arrows and click on the checkmark)