# Put-Request throws 401 [no body] error and cannot be stored in the response entity

Tags: java, spring, request, resttemplate, put

I want to change data on a server via a put request, but I always get a 401 [no body] error. The response looks like the following:

[image]

I do not really understand why I get this error, because my body is not empty. My code looks like this and the values seem to be okay too. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Postman Update:

The values are different right now (consent and authorisation) since its basically a new request but the values were correct before too so this change should not make a difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you call the path segment, URI does not insert these variables. It uses literal values of `consent-id`. Just put them in manually

Comment: Better to copy/paste text to code bocks rather than screenshots where doable. Screenshots are not easily searchable and thus makes the question less valuable to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are simply passing invalid authorization header, or maybe not passing it at all.

What happens is that you make a RestTemplate exchange call, then you get 401 from that request, and Spring propagates it and returns `500 - Internal Server Error`, because there is no error handling in place.

**EDIT**: According to your screenshots, you are not replacing your path variables. Update the way you build your URL as listed below.

```java
Map<String, String> pathVars = new HashMap<>(2);
pathVars.put("consent-id", consentId);
pathVars.put("authorisation-id", authorisationId);

UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(mainLink)
    .path("consents/{consent-id}/authorizations/{authorisation-id}")
    .buildAndExpand(pathVars);
```

Comment: Yes do you have an idea how to fix that? When I do the same request in Postman everything works. I use the same header / body

Comment: post your postman request with headers and everything in here, so I can debug for you

Comment: I updated the question with the postman information. The Authorisation in postman is of type not auth. So this should not be a problem. I think somehow the put is not working correctly. Since all the information seems to be correct

Comment: okay, in your case, you pass your `consent-id` and `authorization-id` as params. However, in postman you can clearly see there are no params, these are path variables. Set them in your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately it still does not work. I do not know what the problem is:( Do you have another idea?

Comment: Make sure your request URL is the same (including path variables and params)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209186/discussion-between-alan-sereb-and-tryhard).

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your authorization-id is correct

if the token has a type for example Bearer you must write so:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer rrdedzfdgf........."
```

and make sure that there is only one space between Bearer and the token

Answer (score 0):

Often the problem comes from the browser locally;
if your site is online, save the part and deploy the last modifications of the site and make the test

otherwise if it is a mobile application test it on a smartphone and not a browser;

in case none of this works, do it with your backend, it works with this

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the I would add an extra character to a password. And Insomnia(Or Postman) would return a JSON response from the server along with a 401 HTTP status code. But when I did the same thing inside a springboot app, when using `catch(HttpServerErrorException e){System.out.prinln(e.getMessage());}` the e.getMessage would have [no body]. I think that is a feature built in the HttpServerErrorException class where it doesn't provide the body for security purposes. Since whoever is requesting is not authorized they should not have access to it.